# C# Issue sourcing image size - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

I am attempting to fit multiple images within the bounds of my screen. I am utilizing a stack panel seeing that this is the best layout for my end goal.
Images from the users local machine should be opened and added to the stack pannel until there is no more screen space to work with.

The issue i am running in to is, when i load my bitmap into memory it is providing me with an inaccurate width (its providing the DPI width however i desire the final width it holds on the screen). ideally, if your screens width is 1000 I would want to load images until 1000 or near 1000 width has been used on screen which is difficult if i cannot source the width of the image (similar to what windows would give me for the width if i looked at the file in explorer)

I am using the following to load the bitmap into memory:

```
          BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
          bitmap.BeginInit();
          bitmap.UriSource = new Uri(fullFilePath, UriKind.Absolute);
          bitmap.EndInit();
          MessageBox.Show(bitmap.Height.ToString() + "is the height. this is the width->" + bitmap.Width.ToString());
```

The Results i am getting are:
1728 is the height
1152 is the width

for an image which is actually 864 x 1296 (a jpg image).

These images are in a stack pannel, would it be possible to extract the size of a specific stack pannel child?
Example `stackpannel.children[0].width`  Something to that effect?

Answer (score 0):

As for BitmapImage, to get its original image size, check `PixelWidth` and `PixelHeight` instead of `Width` and `Height`. It is because `Width` and `Height` values are adjusted with the resolution information contained in the metadata.

For example, if the original width is 864 and X Resolution contained in Exif data is 72, since WPF's standard DPI is 96, the `Width` will be 864 / 72 * 96 = 1152

Comment: Excellent thanks, Do you know of a way i could find out how big it ends up being on the screen? I am willing to use a grid as its parent or any other means which would allow me to get accurate on width / height of pictures or stack panel stacks overall.

Comment: To get actual rendered size of a `Grid` or an `Image` control, refer its `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`. Please note that those values may not be corrent under Per-Monitor DPI environment unless you set the DPI awareness of your app.